# jqPlot step chart not plotting in series order

Tags: javascript, html, jqplot

I need to build a step chart using jQPlot. My X-Axis is Date/Time and my Y-Axis is a number.

Doing this prototype everything runs fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">


<!-- Plot -->
<div id="chart1"></div>

<br />
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var line1 = [['2014-01-15 15:10:01', 21],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 21],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 22],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 22],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 21],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 21],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 22],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 22],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 18],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 18]];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Default Date Axis',
            axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer } },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 1, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

Check the image below. A real step plot:

[image]

But If a add a new value to the series, the plot gets lost.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">


<!-- Plot -->
<div id="chart1"></div>

<br />
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var line1 = [['2014-01-15 15:10:01', 21],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 21],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 22],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 22],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 21],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 21],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 22],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 22],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 18],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 18],
                     ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 21]];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Default Date Axis',
            axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer } },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 1, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

Image:

[image]

Can someone help me to find out what´s going wrong ? I need to keep the step plot (one point connecting to next point in list and so forth).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CategoryAxisRenderer`, it will solve your problem and then you dont have to supply `min` and `max`.

You can keep on adding as much data you want it will always plot it correctly.

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eg2N7/2/)

```
var line1 = [['2014-01-15 15:10:01', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 18],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 18],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 21]];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Default Date Axis',
            axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer } },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 1, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
        });
```

Comment: Indeed worked, but then I lost all of my DateTime automatic axis formatting and some processing now shown here (this code is to isolate the behaviour), as I´ve changed the renderer to a non DateTime format... I really wish to find out why jqPlot is not rendering correctly... After some research I´ve found that this happens only on Chrome, but not on IE... Still looking for a solution that will preserve my date/time data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the sort attribute to false, look:

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.sortData

With this you can make your own sequence.

I am working in a irrigation project, and need circulate irrigate area dynamically, sorry but I don't have reputation to post a picture of it.

Comment: Put some explanation in the answer (in case the link doesn't work your answer would make sense) or else place this as a comment.