# jqPlot simple step plot with date axis not plotting

Tags: javascript, html, plot, jqplot

I have the following jqPlot code that is not doing what I´m expecting. I need to plot a simple  step chart with the given points:

```
var line1 = [['2014-01-15 15:10:01', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 18],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 18]];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Default Date Axis',
            axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer } },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 1, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
        });
```

The plot does not show the step chart. It shows all points together in the right corner of the graph.

Please check out the following fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cox123456a/559f4/)

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CategoryAxisRenderer`, it will solve your problem and then you dont have to supply `min` and `max`.

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eg2N7/1/)

```
var line1 = [['2014-01-15 15:10:01', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 18],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 18]];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Default Date Axis',
            axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer } },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 1, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
        });
```

Comment: Check similar answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145989/jqplot-step-chart-not-plotting-in-series-order

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var line1 = [['2014-01-15 15:10:01', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 21],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 22],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 18],
             ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 18]];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Default Date Axis',
            gridPadding:{right:35},
            axes: {
                xaxis: { 
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    min:'Jan 15, 2014 15:10:00',
                    max:'Jan 15, 2014 15:11:00',
                    tickOptions: { formatString: '%M' }
                } 
            },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 1, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]

});
```

Comment: your data is between small time interval so i set `min:'Jan 15, 2014 15:10:00'` and `max:'Jan 15, 2014 15:11:00'`

Comment: The problem is not related to axis. The problem is that the plot order is not following the given order, and that makes my step chart look differently. By researching I´ve found that this is happening only on Chrome...