# Square Line Chart / Step Chart jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I need to plot 3 series of data, the first is a line and the other 2 are just dots.  However the line should be a step chart (instead of the line drawing from point to point, it should draw the line horizontal and then up to the value

I am stuck as to how to get this with JQPlot.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});
```

The above code would produce the blue line on the below graph, instead I need the green line.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to make comments. Therefore I have to write a new answer.

The already given answer suggests to subtract a small amount from the x value (0.001 in this example) to prevent the triangle effect. But this is not quite accurate and can only be seen as workaround.

The triangle effect is caused by the sorting performed by jqPlot. Sorting is required by most chart types, including line charts. If the data is already sorted before feeding it to jqPlot, sorting can be disabled for jqPlot by setting the sortData attribute to false, see [jqPlot.sortData](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.sortData)

This will prevent the sorting issues and therefore no triangle effect occurs!

You may also want to hide the point markers as jqPlot doesn't know the difference between the real points and our injected artificial points.

```
var data = [3, 7, 9, 1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 5];
var points = [[1, data[0]]];
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    points.push([i + 1, data[i - 1]]);
    points.push([i + 1, data[i]]);
}

var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [points], {
    sortData: false,
    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false
    }
});
```

[Try it in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLgehp9u/)

If you want to get also the point markers right, the only option I see is changing the rendering logic, e.g. writing a step chart plugin.

For reference, see also the answers in the following post: [jqPlot step chart not plotting in series order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22206066/4878880)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify both the x and y value for each point on the graph. The tricky thing is, if two points have the same x value, jqplot may reverse them, which winds up looking like a triangle plot rather than a square. So, the solution is to take each point after the first, subtract a small amount from the x value (in my example, 0.001), and make that the x value for a new point that has the same y value as the point before it. Here's a hard-coded example:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[
    [1,3],  [1.999,3],
    [2,7],  [2.999,7],
    [3,9],  [3.999,9],
    //...
]]);
```

[Try it in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88nbmdhw/).

To create such a list in code, just loop over the original data set and add the necessary extra steps:

```
var data = [3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5];
var points = [[1, data[0]]], len = data.length;
for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    points.push([i + .999, data[i - 1]]);
    points.push([i + 1, data[i]]);
}

var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [points]);
```

[Try it in an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88nbmdhw/1/).

Comment: interesting idea, however if the plot markers are told to display the values how can you counteract this?

Comment: It turns out that with the `pointLabels` plug-in, each data point can have a third parameter which is the label for the data. There is also a `hideZeros` option. Used together, you can set the label for the elements you want to show equal to the y-value, and set the label for the extra elements to zero. [See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/88nbmdhw/2/).